# Reading a QML array property from C++

Tags: c++, qml

Given QML such as:

```
Item {
  objectName: "myitem"
  property var myarr: [1,2,3]
}
```

How can it be read from C++?

The following doesn't work:

```cpp
QObject* item = root->findChild<QObject*>("myitem");
QVariant value = item->property("myarr");
```

While `value.isValid()` returns true, if I query `QMetaType::typeName( QMetaType::Type(int(value.type())) )`
it yields "QWidget*".

(Using Qt 5.9.4 on x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a list of QVariant since it is the most generic type, in the next example I unpack it and store it in a container:

```
if(QObject *item = root->findChild<QObject *>("myitem")){
    std::vector<int> vector; // another option std::vector<float>;
    for(const QVariant & v: item->property("myarr").toList()){
       vector.push_back(v.toInt()); // another option toFloat();
    }
    qDebug() << vector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  On a related note - any clue how to detect if the property is a list or something else (e.g. a map)?  If I call `value.canConvert(QMetaType::Type::QVariantList)` it returns true, but so does `canConvert(QMetaType::Type::QVariantMap))`

Comment: @DavidJ I do not prefer to obtain data from QML to C ++, that method always brings compatibility problems, instead I create a QObject that has qproperties that manage the business logic and export it using setContextProperty. The problem you have had now is not dangerous but for example QML creates and removes elements dynamically and say you get the item but QML deletes it so the pointer will point to non-reserved memory. I recommend you read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c

Comment: That isn't possible in this instance as the properties belong to dynamically created & loaded QML generated from cross-translation from another declarative markup language.